# Keyframes with jquery not working in opera

Tags: jquery, opera, css-animations

```
$.fn.addKeyframe([{
        name: "spinrd",
        "from": tr + ':rotate(' + (rX1 + 0) + 'deg);',
        "to": tr + ':rotate(' + (rX1 + 360) + 'deg);',
    }]);
```

I have a sequence of this code, it is working fine in firefox chrome and ie10 while it is not working in opera.

This is the jquery plugin https://github.com/krazyjakee/jQuery-Keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of the keyframes jquery plugin might be that the prefixes are not working properly since this plugin uses sniffing. I solved with Modernizr and transit in different scenarios.